# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'. Flutter Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am just new to flutter and I wanted to test a github project

```
  List<Rasp> _raspListFromSnapshots(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
  return Rasp(
    modelNumber: doc.data()['modelNumber'] ?? '',
    address: doc.data()['address'] ?? '',
    software: doc.data()['software'] ?? '',
    finder: doc.data()['finder'] ?? null,
    user: doc.data()['user'] ?? null,
    owner: doc.data()['owner'] ?? null,
    other: doc.data()['other'] ?? '',
    geoPoint: doc.data()['geoPoint'] ?? null,
  );
}).toList();
```

}

```
  List<UserData> _userListFromSnapshots(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
  return UserData(
    uid: doc.data()['uid'],
    phoneNumber: doc.data()['phoneNumber'],
    username: doc.data()['username'],
    email: doc.data()['email'],
  );
}).toList();
```

}

all the things inside [' '] has an error saying The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.  Try defining the operator '[]'.

what should I do with this? please help

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63663853/class-querydocumentsnapshot-has-no-instance-method-receiver-instance-of

Comment: please check the duplicate provided https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610111/after-updating-cloud-firestore-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-ob