# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]' error

Tags: flutter, dart

```
body: Center(
    child: Container(
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      //color: Colors.black,
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: firestore.collection("users").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            return new ListView(
              children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot){
                return Card(
                  child: Text(documentSnapshot.data()!["Name"]),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

**["Name"]** shows error **The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' has no instance method '\[\]'. Receiver: Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' Tried calling: \[\] ("name")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63663853/class-querydocumentsnapshot-has-no-instance-method-receiver-instance-of)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The operator '\[\]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'. Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60245865/the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-class-object-dart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast your `documentSnapshot.data()` to `DocumentSnapshot` correct type:

```
(documentSnapshot.data() as DocumentSnapshot)["Name"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast like this:

```
(documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['Name']
```

Comment: This is what worked for me.